# Восстановление пароля из коробки Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Насколько известно в ларавел есть уже готовая наработка восстановаление пароля. Прописал маршруты как указаны в документации, сделал вьюхи. Прохожу по /password/email, а он сволочь редиректит на главную. Подскажите хотя бы где копать?

Comment: Sorry Промазал не вам ответ писал.

Comment: Начните со списка путей http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/5/listing-your-routes

Answer (score 1):

**E_p**, спасибо за отклик. Вчера появилась мысля и оказалась верной. Перенёс Контроллер из директории Auth в корневую контроллеров и всё заработало. Видимо связано с тем, что с аутентификацией ранее сделал также.